# Injecting a validation class Instance to unit test - phpunit

Tags: php, unit-testing, validation, oop, phpunit

I'm testing a class named City that accepts two parameters, in this class i have a name getter that return a trimmed / filtered string.

**Problem**

If i want to use a custom validation class, i'll have to inject it through the constructor. and i'll have to create a real object in a my test.

**Question**

- Should i create a validation object and pass it to City class in my test? since i can't use a mock for this one.
- Am i breaking the unit test isolation here?

**City Class**

```
class City 
{
    protected $name;
    protected $shortCode;

    public function __construct($name, $shortCode)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->shortCode = $shortCode;
    }

    public function name()
    {
         return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z]/', '', trim($this->name));
    }
}
```

**City Class after injecting a validation class**

```
class City 
{
    protected $name;
    protected $shortCode;
    protected $customValidation;


    public function __construct($name, $shortCode, CustomValidation $customValidation)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->shortCode = $shortCode;
        $this->customValidation = $customValidation;

    }

    public function name()
    {
        return $this->customValidation->trimmed_no_special_characters($this->name);

    }
}
```

**Test**

```
class CityTest extends TestCase
{
    protected $city;

    public function setUp()
    {

        $this->city = new City('Dubai', 'DXB');

    }
}
```

**Test after injecting the validation class**

```
class CityTest extends TestCase
{

    protected $city;

    public function setUp()
    {

        $this->city = new City('Dubai', 'DXB', new CustomValidation('Dubai'));

    }
}
```

Comment: Why exactly cant you use a mock?

Comment: because the name getter in city class uses a method for validation, am not sure what to do, or if i can use a mock or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just mock the necessary method:

```
$validate = $this
    ->getMockBuilder(CustomValidation::class)
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->getMock();

$validate
    ->expects($this->once())
    ->method('trimmed_no_special_characters')
    ->will($this->returnValue('some trimmed name));
```

You can also make a method's mock, that expects a specific input by chaining in
 this call: 
`->with($this->equalTo('something'))`

Comment: [As of PHPUnit 5.4.0 getMock() method has been deprecated. Please use createMock()](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/Release-Announcement-for-PHPUnit-5.4.0)

Comment: @NikitaU. the `getMock()` (in the example code) is being called on `MockBuilder` and not on `TestCase`.

Comment: Sorry for dumb comment